# Correct gauge of wire to power 2 ceiling lightnings

Tags: lighting, ceiling, light-fixture, safety, wire

I was attempting a simple home improvement project that has slowly become a bigger job than I expected.

So my aunt had a light bulb hanging from the ceiling in the corridor and wanted it replaced with a "chandelier". I thought I could hang the chandelier in the electrical box but it turned out to be a fake ceiling and long story short the beam where I ended up hanging the thing is not close to the electric box on the ceiling that powers the lamp.

Adding to this she asked me to put a second chandelier opposite of the first one.

My question is, can I use a short 1.5mm2 wire connected to the box, use a wago 3 holes connector and power the 2 chandeliers each 1,5m from the box is opposite directions with 10, 40 watt bulbs each?

Or would this be too much for the wires to handle? I cant really make the math and I don't feel secure in my calculations.

I don't exactly know what gauge of wire is beyond the electrical box. The breaker in the electrical box for the lights is 10 amps. I'm in Denmark, so if someone also knows where I can read the Danish code about such things it would be helpful.

As an additional question, the wires are both "separated" just the blue and brown and I was going to run them trough a plastic "rail" that is a full cover, can this be problematic? (I mean do to heat, do these even heat much?)

If the two chandeliers are too much, would one be ok?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning right out what country you are in. I can't count the number of electrical postings where you have to ask "where are you located?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.5 wire needs to be protected by a 16 Amp (or weaker) breaker. You are fine on that front.

Your total wattage will be `10*40W*2 = 800W`; on a 220V line this will mean `800W / 220V = 3.6 Amps`. So overload is not an issue assuming there is nothing else on that breaker. (If there is then add the wattage to the 800W and divide again)

You should also extend the ground wire if there is one, this is a green/yellow wire and should be connected to the ground connection of the chandelier.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but by connecting both chandeliers to a single (blue and brown) wire into the box this single 1.5mm2 wire would have to supply 800W? If so, the cable I have is H07 V-U which I think is 450/720V rated. I just would like to know what that means and how I should take that into account.

Comment: @Marty The 450/720V only refers to voltage, Denmark uses 220V I believe. According to [a spec sheet I found](http://www.chakira-cables.com/images/fiche_tech/ho7v-u-r.pdf) it can easily carry more than 10 Amps (the rating of the breaker protecting it) which is 2200 Watts.